# In 12 grid bootstrap system is there a need to design for each and every breakpoint?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, web

I have already provided designs for 1920*1080 and 360*760 will be providing designs for the tablet version so is there a need to provide designs of every breakpoint or can it be made responsive with 3 designs for desktop tablet and mobile and can these designs be used for Mac as well, I have specified the breakpoints below.
360px to 719px
720px to 1079px
1080px to 1295px
1260px to 1439px
1800pn to ..

Comment: You can have as many, or as few, breakpoints as you want.

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on your design. It is often not necessary to use all breakpoints. 3 breakpoints can be enough. The breakpoints often also come in handy for adjusting individual elements of your design.